# Moving files from PC to MAC

Tags: c#, macos

I want to ask how can I copy files from PC to MAC using C#. Also my application will create new folder when needed and copy / move files in them

Comment: Find flash named C#, connect to pc move files to flash, disconnect...connect to mac, move files to mac. Done. :)

Comment: where does C# come into this? Sounds like a shell script what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By which technology you want to move files ?

1- Over the network ? using Directory access protocols ?
2- Through Web ?

Each has different aspects. as for network you just need to have access to mac on windows computer and tell them path. using `**SYSTEM.IO**` name space you can easily copy files from one directory[Windows] to other[MAC] using their path. Window will take care of permissions but be sure the user which you are using to access has write permission to folder where you are copying files.

Through web you might need to implement web programming to read and write each file you post.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I'll be copying/moving it over the network.

Comment: Also my application will create new folder when needed and copy/move files in them.

Comment: Thanks i thought because of different disk format it would be difficult to do these simple tasks. but System.IO does the trick.

Comment: Well, it is more trick of Backend Directory Services which makes it completely transparent to user how they need to copy files between different operating systems. System.IO is upper level layer.